# Sharing Files on a home network

Tags: windows-7, windows, file-sharing

Is it possible for me to actually "share" a data file (Quicken) between two Windows 7 computers on my home network?

Comment: At the same time, no, but if it is a program, yes, you can set up a network share. Or, if it is just a data file (like a .qkn or whatever), you sure can.

Comment: Create a share, put file on share, access with any computer - this process has several methods depending on your level of comfort with network sharing (but uSlackr's suggestion is probably the best way to go if you are not familiar with networking/permissions). To access at the same time requires multi-user mode, which quicken does not support, the file will report as locked. Quickbooks however will let you use multi-user mode and you can have two computer open it at the same time.

Comment: This will also require the program to support [UNC addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Naming_Convention#Uniform_Naming_Convention) for data files, if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: @echoback, UNC paths are only necessary if the share does not show up as a drive/folder in explorer (usually like a mapped drive). I'm not sure if home groups do that (as they aren't exactly mapped drives) or if they just essentially create a UNC shortcut to a remote machine. I'm not sure if the default .net file open dialog includes the home groups even, which may even be moot if the application uses a custom UI for that dialog instead of invoking the built in one for .net. So, hopefully someone will be able to clarify  some of this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a HomeGroup during install?  A Homegroup can make the process of file sharing pretty straight forward.

There is a nice tutorial from Microsoft here that will walk you through the process:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/help/homegroup-from-start-to-finish